# XSL loop from 1 to variable

Tags: xml, loops, xslt

XML:

```
<paginering>
 <pagineringButtons>
  <field name="pagineringButtonExcel" type="button"></field>
  <field name="pagineringButtonPrint" type="button"></field>
 </pagineringButtons>
 <field name="pagineringPaginas" type="text"></field>
 <field name="pagineringSelect" type="selectChosen">
 <fieldOption id="10"><![CDATA[10]]></fieldOption>
 <fieldOption id="100"><![CDATA[100]]></fieldOption>
 <fieldOption id="20"><![CDATA[20]]></fieldOption>
 <fieldOption id="50"><![CDATA[50]]></fieldOption>
 <init id=""> </init></field>
</paginering>
```

XSL:

```
<ul class="paginering">
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vorige</a></li>
 <xsl:variable name="aantalRijen">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(//row[@type='data'])" />
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="aantalPaginas">
  <xsl:value-of select="ceiling($aantalRijen div 10)" />
 </xsl:variable>
 <li><xsl:value-of select="ceiling($aantalRijen div 10)" /></li>
  <xsl:if test="not($num = $aantalPaginas)">
   <xsl:call-template name="writePagenumbers">
    <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num + 1" />
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Volgende</a></li>
</ul>

<xsl:template name="writePagenumbers">
 <xsl:param name="num" />
 <li><xsl:value-of select="num"/></li>
</xsl:template>
```

The value of 'aantalPaginas' is equal to 18.

Wanted HTML:

```
<ul class="paginering">
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vorige</a></li>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
 <li>6</li>
 <li>7</li>
 <li>8</li>
 <li>9</li>
 <li>10</li>
 <li>11</li>
 <li>12</li>
 <li>13</li>
 <li>14</li>
 <li>15</li>
 <li>16</li>
 <li>17</li>
 <li>18</li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Volgende</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I make a good loop from 1 to 18? The result I get right now is 1 'li' with the inner value of '18', and 1 'li' with no inner value. How can I make this right?

**Edit:**
The `<li>18</li>` is coming from out of the wanted loop. I only need to make the `<li></li>` right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `num` variable is initially set to 18, you can perform a recursive call on the `writePagenumbers` template

```
<xsl:template name="writePagenumbers">
   <xsl:param name="num" />
   <xsl:param name="current" select="1" />
   <li><xsl:value-of select="$current"/></li>
   <xsl:if test="$current &lt; $num">
      <xsl:call-template name="writePagenumbers">
          <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num" />
          <xsl:with-param name="current" select="$current+ 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

If you were using XSLT 2.0 though, you could write it like this

```
<xsl:template name="writePagenumbers">
   <xsl:param name="num" />
   <xsl:for-each select="1 to $num">
       <pre><xsl:value-of select="."/></pre>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: My apologies. I've corrected my answer. You set the parameter `num` to 18 (or anything) when you call the template, and it is `current` variable that goes from 1 to 18.

Comment: Just had to change `<xsl:value-of select="num"/>` to `<xsl:value-of select="$current"/>`, works great now, thanks!.